# How to define probability mass function of random variable $X$ when probability measure associated with the probability space is lacking information?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From some of the reading I have done, it seems like a random  variable $X$ is *not* defined with respect to a sample space $\Omega$ in "isolation".  Instead, $X$ is defined on $\Omega$ in the context of *a specific probability space*: $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$.

If this is true, consider the example of $\Omega=\{A,B,C\}$, where $\mathcal F=\big\{\{\},\{A\},\{B,C\},\Omega\big\}$ (which obeys the properties of a $\sigma$-algebra).

Suppose the accompanying probability measure $P$ of *this* probability space has the mapping rules: $\{\} \mapsto 0$, $\{A\}\mapsto 0.5$, $\{B,C\}\mapsto 0.5$, and $\Omega \mapsto 1$.

Next, let the random variable $X$ be defined on the sample space $\Omega$ in the context of the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ with the following mappings: $A  \mapsto 10$, $B \mapsto  20$, and $C \mapsto 30$.

> Is it invalid to ask for a complete description of the probability mass function (PMF) of the random variable $X$?

The issue seems to be that $P$ has not provided us with the relevant information to deduce a *specific* PMF of $X$. Instead, the PMF could be any function that satisfies: $10 \mapsto 0.5$, $20 \mapsto \alpha$, and $30 \mapsto \beta$ such that $\alpha+\beta=0.5$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The issue is that $X$ isn't exactly a random variable on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$.  Part of the definition of a random variable on a probability space usually includes that it be measurable with respect to $\mathcal F$.  This $X$ is not $\mathcal F$-measurable, though.

Comment: @user6247850 I see. Does there exist *any* $\mathcal F$-measurable random variable for the probability space I have defined? (Thank you for the input) Or does my post actually illustrate why there can be no $\mathcal F$-measurable random variable for this defined probability space

Comment: Yes, any function with $X(B)=X(C)$ will be measurable with respect to the $\mathcal{F}$ you provided.

Comment: @JasonSwanson ahhh, got it. Thank you. So is it a conceptually accurate understanding to say that, in the context of a discrete random variable, "If you cannot deduce a unique PMF arising from your defined mapping $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$, then $X$ is not a random variable (where $\Omega$ is derived from the context of the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$)?"

Comment: Conceptually, I'd say that's accurate. The measurability assumption is what ensures that the distribution of the random variable is well-defined. So if the distribution is not well-defined, and everything else is correct, then it must be the measurability condition that fails.